# php - redirect ajax requests

Tags: php, wordpress, http-redirect

How can I redirect an ajax request in php/wordpress.

I tried `header("Location: " . "http://redirect.url");` but it doesn't work, the response has `301 Moved Permanently` status and the request fails.

Comment: Browsers will silently follow 301 redirects for Ajax requests. Whatever the problem is, it must be with what you are redirecting to.

Comment: try accessing the http://redirect.url directly from ajax, not by redirection, see if it works, if it does not then that redirected URL has the problem, not ajax:)

Comment: The redirect.url works from ajax and if I paste in the browser's url bar I get the expected response.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot redirect from php by an ajax request. Instead of that you need to do it inside your javascript.

For example if this is your ajax then after success  of your request redirect from ajax itself

```
$.ajax({
    type    : 'post',
    url     : 'http://localhost/redirect.php',
    success : function(data){
       window.location = "http://your/url";
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to redirect the request itself not the page.