# Execute PHP redirect after ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, slim

For a banking application I need to redirect the user to an external login page if (and only if) the access token is invalid. This redirect can only be triggered from the server as this access token is never sent to the client.

PHP looks like this (using the Slim framework) :

```
$app->get( '/banking', function ( \Slim\Http\Request $request, \Slim\Http\Response $response, $args ) {
    if( token == valid ) {
      // do your stuff
    } else {

        $banking = new Banking();
        $connection = $banking->getConnection();
        return $response->withHeader( 'Location', $connection->login_url( 'someRandomString' ) );
        }
    } );
```

`$connection->login_url()` generates the URL I want to redirect to. jQuery however doesn't redirect me to that page but instead loads the page content into the response string of the success callback function. (I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801977/php-redirect-ajax-requests) that browsers would just follow the redirection silently)

Is there a way to force the client to actually redirect the page or to help javascript find out that it actually should redirect to the external page instead of loading the content into the script? How?

Comment: return a json response with the redirect url as a property, parse that in your javascript and perform the redirect client side

Comment: By definition you won't be able to redirect server-side with AJAX

Comment: If you show your javascript an answer can be provided

Comment: @Jonathan: nothing special there, just an ordinary `$.get( url, data, function ( response )  { ... });`

Comment: @Tekay37 and `window.location = "<redirecturl>";`

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution, but I'll have about 20-30 such request where I would have to handle this case. I would appreciate a more generic ( and "DRY" ) approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the status to 302 too so that the browser does the redirect.

```php
$response = $response->withStatus(302);
return $response->withHeader('Location', $connection->login_url( 'someRandomString' ) );
```

Alternatively, as you're using Slim, you can use [withRedirect](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Http/Response.php#L266-L291):

```php
return $response->withRedirect($connection->login_url('someRandomString'));
```